# loop through a list of objects with utc and remove the object with oldest utc java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a list like below

```
"pList": [
   {
    "Utc": "2021-12-20T05:10:20+0000",
    "key": {
     "num": "23131"
    }
   },
   {
    "Utc": "2021-12-20T05:15:20+0000",
    "key": {
     "num": "23131"
    }
   },
   {
    "Utc": "2021-12-20T05:20:20+0000",
    "key": {
     "num": "23131"
    }
   }
  ]
```

now , i need to loop through this list and delete the oldest utc. How do i achieve this in java ? (List should contain 2 items at given instance. I need to look for the oldest utc item and remove it from the list)

This is what i have tried

```
if(pList.size() > 2) {

                   for(int i = 1; i < pList.size() ; i++ ) {
                     Instant prior = pList.get( i - 1 ).Utc();
                        Instant current = pList.get( i ).Utc();
                        if(prior.isBefore(current)) {
                            pList.remove(i);
                        }
                   }
                   
                  }
```

Comment: what did you try so far? this is not a code-writing service, we can help answer a *specific* question if you have one, but this question sounds like it's asking for ready code, and it is not even clear what, exactly, you want this code to do.

Comment: I would have easily done this if ts with JS , Im new to Java. I was searching online on how to loop through an arraylist and compare object properties. I couldn't find any good examples which compared dates. Being kind to each other helps community growth

Comment: if you are looking to remove the oldest utc, why not just have a variable pointing towards the current oldest utc found? as you iterate through the list, update if an older utc is found. After finish iterating. remove the oldest utc based on the variable. The logic of the code you wrote already has issues as you are not removing the oldest utc, rather the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how i implemented it,

```
                  if(pList.size() > 2) {
                   for(int i = 1; i < pList.size() ; i++ ) {
                     Instant prior = pList.get( i - 1 ).getUtc();
                        Instant current = pList.get( i ).getUtc();
                        if(prior.isBefore(current)) {
                            pList.remove(i-1);
                        }
                   }
                  }
```

It made sure that pList has only 2 items at given instance and removed the oldest if there's a new item coming into the list.